# How to add call back for multiple parameters? - Angular5 breadcrumb

Tags: angular

I Have the following routes

```
/accounts/
/accounts/:accountId
/accounts/:accountId/branches
/accounts/:accountId/branches/:branchId
```

I've successfully replaced the accountId with a account name in the breadcrumb

```
Accounts / Account Name
Accounts / Account Name / Branches
Accounts / Account Name / Branches / Branch ID
```

by doing

```
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'ng5-breadcrumb';

constructor(private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
      this.breadcrumbService.addCallbackForRoute('/accounts/6e440587-3c9e-11e8-89d7-408d5cbccb60', this.getNameForAccount);
      this.breadcrumbService.addCallbackForRouteRegex('^/accounts/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', this.getNameForAccount);
    }

    getNameForAccount(id:string):string {
      console.log(id);
      debugger
      return 'specific name for account with id';
    }
```

But I'm unable to replace the BranchId as well. My goal is to create a breadcrumb like this:

```
Accounts / Account Name / Branches / Branch Name
```

Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not specified, i have to assume that `breadcrumbService.addCallbackForRoute` takes in 2 parameters. A string and a callback function. Instead make it accept a string and an array of callback functions. That way you can iterate the array and execute the callbacks.

edit

I'm sorry, i didn't notice the library. I think you can add another callback just for the branches route just like you did for accounts: `this.breadcrumbService.addCallbackForRoute('/branches/6e440587-3c9e-11e8-89d7-408d5cbccb60', this.getNameForBranch);`

Comment: import { BreadcrumbService } from 'ng5-breadcrumb';
Do i need to create a custom breadcrumb service?

Comment: This doesnot seem to work. I tried the above code, but when the url is taken, it is not entering getNameForBranch method.